# RDS Gateway > Update Resource authorization policies with Powershell

Tags: powershell, remote-desktop, rds

I wonder if it exists a powershell command to edit the **RD Gateway Manager > Resource Authorization Policies** as shown on below screenshot.

[image: RDS Gateway]

I would like to edit the 'Manage Local Computer Group' and add a computer in a a group
I try to get information about RD CAP but i'm not sure where to go.

Thx for your help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The settings are stored in the path:
`RDS:\GatewayServer\GatewayManagedComputerGroups`

You can try this way to add computers to the group by using powershell:

```bsh
Import-Module RemoteDesktopServices
Get-Command -Module RemoteDesktopServices
New-Item -Path RDS:\GatewayServer\GatewayManagedComputerGroups\$GroupsName\Computers -Name $computer
```

If you want to get more details, `cd RDS:\GatewayServer\GatewayManagedComputerGroups` to have a look can help you a lot.